# When StageVideo is being rendered by software, black screen and audio only on Android. When hardware accelerated, everything works

Tags: android, air, hardware-acceleration

We developed an Android app using Adobe AIR. We basically loop HD and FullHD H.264 videos using the StageVideo resource, that takes benefit from hardware acceleration.

This app is running perfectly on our Yarvik Noble tablet and on our Tronsmart MK908. On the Vega sometimes we get a black screen with audio, but on some other times it works perfectly. There is no pattern or specific video, it sometimes happens and then gets back to normal.

We did some other tests and found out that the Vega swaps between HARDWARE ACCELERATION (works perfectly) and SOFTWARE (black screen with audio). The strange thing about it is that the same video sometimes is decoded in one way and some other times in the other way.

Meanwhile our other hardwares always decode the vídeos using HARDWARE ACCELERATION.

I shot a small video showing the problem. As soon the app is opened, the video on the tablet (muted) is perfectly displayed while the TV (not muted) displays a black screen and just the audio. A very curious fact is that there is no pattern to repeat the problem. Sometimes the first video works and other videos fail.

Video - http://hahmann.com.br/air/IMG_7104.mp4

All the Vega S89 units we own are Android 4.4.2, Build 108k4 and Kernel 3.10.33.

Apk and source - http://hahmann.com.br/air/source_apk.zip

Bug opened at Adobe - bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3836848

I appreciate some help.

Best Regards,
Peter